# Insert several data in BIGQUERY in a column of type RECORD

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a table in bigquery with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
  name STRING,
  values STRUCT<model STRING, group BOOL>
)
```

What I want is to insert several data in the values column related to the same name.

This is what I'm doing:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE  (name ,values)
VALUES (
  'export',
  STRUCT('model1', false)
),
(
  'export',
  STRUCT('model2', true)
)
```

This is what I get:

| name | values.model | values.group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| export | model1 | false |
| export | model2 | true |

This is what I want:

| name | values.model | values.group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| export | model1 | false |
|  | model2 | true |

How can I insert several data for in the RECORS type column for the name column without having to repeat all the data? I need a record for each name, but that contains several values.
I don't know if this is the correct way to create the table to achieve this.

Comment: `values` should be `ARRAY<STRUCT<model STRING, group BOOL>>` type for your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE MY_TABLE (
  name STRING,
  values ARRAY<STRUCT<model STRING, `group` BOOL>>
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (name ,values)
VALUES ( 'export', [STRUCT('model1', false), STRUCT('model2', true)] ),
       ( 'import', [STRUCT('model3', true), STRUCT('model4', false)] )
;

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE;
```

**Query results**

[image]

or,

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE MY_TABLE AS
SELECT 'export' AS name, 
       [STRUCT('model1' AS model, false AS `group`), ('model2', true)] AS values
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'import', [('model3', true), ('model4', false)] AS values;
```

Comment: How can I insert another record related to the same column after having inserted several records for that column. For example, now there are model1 and model2 for export, how can I add model3 later? I tried INSERT but it doesn't work, is it necessary to add it with an UPDATE?

Comment: You need a *UPDATE* query to add a *struct* element to an existing array of *struct*.